# Query to get list of Inventory Items for which there is no material transaction in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Have a small doubt I want to compile a SQL query in Inventory where I have to get those Items for which transactions have not been recorded during a period of at least a specified number of days.

The days could be 30 days or 2 months depends. So I want to get those items for which no transaction was recorded for lets say 30 days. Could anyone give me an idea of how to go about this thing?? I am using r12. I came up with the following query but it is giving many records. The commented portions of this query remains commented only

```
select distinct msi.segment1, msi.description, msi.primary_uom_code,
                msi.inventory_item_id
  from mtl_system_items_b msi /*,
 mtl_material_transactions mmt*/
 where /*msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
    AND msi.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
    AND NVL((SELECT SUM(transaction_quantity)
              FROM mtl_onhand_quantities
             WHERE inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id),
            0) = 0
    AND TRUNC(mmt.transaction_date) <= SYSDATE - &D
    AND*/
      not exists
          (select *
             from mtl_material_transactions mmt
            where msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
              and msi.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
              and trunc(mmt.transaction_date) < sysdate - &D)
```

Comment: Unless you have an index on TRUNC(mmt.transaction_date), I'd index mmt.transaction_date and change the last line to "mmt.transaction_date < SYSDATE - &D + 1". The logic looks reasonable, though you should clean up the formatting and remove the commented out clauses that obscure what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks David.. However 1 doubt why would you use mmt.transaction_date < SYSDATE - &D + 1??

Comment: To be able to use an index, which a predicate on trunc(mmt.transaction_date) wouldn't normally allow: actually you'd want to index (inventory_item_id,  mmt.organization_id, mmt.transaction_date)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of your query that will give all items with on hand inventory that have not been transacted in a determined number of days.

```
select distinct msi.segment1
    ,msi.description
    ,msi.primary_uom_code
    --,msi.inventory_item_id
    ,q.organization_id
    ,q.quantity
from mtl_system_items_b msi
    join (SELECT inventory_item_id, organization_id, SUM(transaction_quantity) quantity
          FROM mtl_onhand_quantities
          GROUP BY inventory_item_id, organization_id) q on msi.inventory_item_id = q.inventory_item_id and msi.organization_id=q.organization_id   
where not exists (select *
                  from mtl_material_transactions mmt
                  where msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
                      and msi.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
                      and trunc(mmt.transaction_date) > sysdate - 180)
order by q.organization_id,msi.segment1;
```